# Pinia defineStore returns function. How this function implements protection of SSR pollutions?

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering, pinia

I can not understand how function returned by defineStore binds with request context on SSR. Function created once and executes with different context for each request.

```
# some-moddule.ts

export default defineStore(
   'storeId',
   () => { ... }
)

# some-component.vue
import useSomeModule from 'some-module.ts'

.... 
const someModule = useSomeModule()
```

Calling useSomeModule() is SSR savely. But the calling does not have info about request context. So it is not clear for me how it bind request context to call.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean, could you explain yourself better? Or have you tried looking for what you need in the official Pinia documentation?

Comment: I updated qustion. I hope I was able to explain.